# Can't update to 20.10

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade

Results of `sudo do-release-upgrade` :

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release 
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [819 B]                   
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1.338 kB]                                       
Fetched 1.339 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                      
authenticate 'groovy.tar.gz' against 'groovy.tar.gz.gpg'  
extracting 'groovy.tar.gz'
Reading cache
Checking package manager 
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done 
Hit http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease     
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                 
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/system76/pop/ubuntu focal InRelease     
Hit http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease   
Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)                                           
Reading package lists... Done     
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done
Checking for installed snaps
Calculating snap size requirements
Updating repository information
Traceback (most recent call last):   File
 "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-1p89v3_w/groovy", line 8, in <module>
     sys.exit(main())   File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-1p89v3_w/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeMain.py",
line 238, in main
```

> if app.run():   File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-1p89v3_w/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 2089, in run
> return self.fullUpgrade()   File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-1p89v3_w/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py",
> line 1932, in fullUpgrade
> if not self.updateSourcesList():   File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-1p89v3_w/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py",
> line 801, in updateSourcesList
> self.sources = SourcesList(matcherPath=self.datadir)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/sourceslist.py", line 273,
> in **init**
> self.matcher = SourceEntryMatcher(matcherPath)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/sourceslist.py", line 470,
> in **init**
> dist = DistInfo(base_dir=matcherPath)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/distinfo.py", line 184, in
> **init**
> with open(dist_fname) as dist_file: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
> '/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-1p89v3_w/Pop.info' Error in
> sys.excepthook: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/problem_report.py", line 477, in
> add_to_existing
> self.write(f)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/problem_report.py", line 430, in write
> block = f.read(1048576)   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
> (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final) UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position
> 1: invalid start byte
>
> Original exception was: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-1p89v3_w/groovy", line 8, in 
> sys.exit(main())   File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-1p89v3_w/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeMain.py",
> line 238, in main
> if app.run():   File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-1p89v3_w/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py",
> line 2089, in run
> return self.fullUpgrade()   File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-1p89v3_w/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py",
> line 1932, in fullUpgrade
> if not self.updateSourcesList():   File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-1p89v3_w/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py",
> line 801, in updateSourcesList
> self.sources = SourcesList(matcherPath=self.datadir)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/sourceslist.py", line 273,
> in **init**
> self.matcher = SourceEntryMatcher(matcherPath)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/sourceslist.py", line 470,
> in **init**
> dist = DistInfo(base_dir=matcherPath)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/distinfo.py", line 184, in
> **init**

```
    with open(dist_fname) as dist_file: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
> '/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-1p89v3_w/Pop.info'
```

EDIT:

```
sudo apt install ppa-purge
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  aptitude
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ppa-purge
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 6.312 B of archives.
After this operation, 24,6 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 ppa-purge all 0.2.8+bzr63 [6.312 B]
Fetched 6.312 B in 0s (14,3 kB/s)     
Selecting previously unselected package ppa-purge.
(Reading database ... 327513 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../ppa-purge_0.2.8+bzr63_all.deb ...
Unpacking ppa-purge (0.2.8+bzr63) ...
Setting up ppa-purge (0.2.8+bzr63) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
x@x:~$ sudo ppa-purge ppa:system76/pop
Updating packages lists
PPA to be removed: system76 pop
Warning:  Could not find package list for PPA: system76 pop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was running into the same 'missing Pop.info' error while attempting to upgrade to Pop! OS 20.10. I was able to work around it with the following procedure:

```
# Begin upgrade
sudo do-release-upgrade
# Pause the process with Ctrl-Z
^Z
# Create an empty Pop.info file in the newest /tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-* directory
sudo touch /tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrade-*/Pop.info
# Resume the upgrade process
fg
```

Comment: sudo touch /tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrade-*/Pop.info
touch: cannot touch '/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrade-*/Pop.info': No such file or directory

Comment: My rel file is named ubuntu-release-upgrader-xk5bchr_ and now it's working :)

Comment: @newcat1000 Glad to hear it. The name of the directory is random and will be different each time.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @cwc 's answer,

```
# Begin upgrade
sudo do-release-upgrade

# Pause the process with Ctrl-Z
^Z

# Find the tmp folder that newly created. And store LAST_CREATED_FOLDER variable.
LAST_CREATED_FOLDER=$(sudo ls -t /tmp/ | grep ubuntu-release-upgrader | head -1)

# Create an empty Pop.info file in the newest /tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-* directory
sudo touch /tmp/$LAST_CREATED_FOLDER/Pop.info

# Resume the upgrade process
fg
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. If your post is meant to improve an existing answer rather than suggesting a different kind of solution, please don't post it as a new answer. Rather, place a comment below the answer you want to improve, or submit an edit suggestion that would incorporate your improvements to that answer.